# Admob and publishing app?

Tags: android, android-studio, admob, google-play-services

My App is ready and i also included the ads in it using test ad unit id, I just want to know, when I upload it on play_store and then in admob I choose my app and generate ad unit ids, should I need to manually update the ad unit ids in my app and then re_upload it on play_store or admob do this thing automatically.

Comment: Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to manually add any new ad unit you create and update the app. Admob doesn't do that automatically.

After adding the new ad units, you will have to rebuild the apk and upload it